# Can I take my name out of a car loan?

Tags: loans, bank-account, car, co-sign

I am in the process of buying a house and the bank requires that my name needs to be taken out of the car loan. My son is the cosigner, and my daughter (whom I bought the car for) is making the monthly payments. What would I have to do to get my name out?

Comment: I deleted my answer after finding the duplicate, but if she can't refinance the car in her name (or can't afford the payments of the new loan) then you'll need to either keep your name on the loan or sell the car and get a cheaper one.

Comment: Your daughter (and/or son) needs to convince a lender that she (they) can afford the loan without having you as a guarantor. Whether or not this is the same lender which currently has the loan doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Which country ?

Comment: Are you one that the dealership sold the car to (even though your daughter is making the monthly payments)?  Also, the fact that your son had to cosign the loan makes me think that your credit score is pretty low.

Comment: @DStanley this doesn't appear do be a duplicate, because OP appears to be the "primary" signer, not the cosigner.